# Horizontal noise on RCA capture

Tags: video-capture, noise

I'm trying to record some Wii footage using a Silvercrest capture card. I've managed to get the drivers working and recorded a snippet via an RCA A/V cable.

However, there's a weird kind of noise - some of the lines are randomly displaced to the left.

I know it's not interlacing, but different kind of noise that I don't know how to fix:

[image: noise sample]

1. Are there ways to prevent this noise from appearing on capture output?
2. Are there ways to fix such errors in post?

Comment: Welcome! My guess is that the setup/black level out of the Wii isn't matching what the capture card expects. But that's just a guess without seeing the signal through a waveform/vectorscope and knowing about the capture card. (Plus it has been a _long_ time since I did much analog troubleshooting.) In a professional environment, I'd run the analog through a [TBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_base_correction)/[Frame Sync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_synchronization_(video)). That's really the only way to prevent it. You can't fix it in post, other than painting every frame.

Comment: Answer to question two: definitely not. If you capture that, you're stuck with that.

Comment: If your capture device has a gain, fiddle with that. I had a similar image artifact with a VGA to ethernet years ago, and dialing the gain just right made it better, but never fully got rid of it.